# Add default custom taxonomy to plugin activation

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I have a plugin created with boilerplate from this site:
https://wppb.me/

And I would like to understand how to automatically add 4 entries in the custom taxonomy category that I have already processed.

I guess this code goes on the activator.php file, but I don't know what code to apply to automatically generate these 4 categories.

Can you guys help me?

**UPDATE:**

Flipping around a bit more I found this code, but it still doesn't work. Is there perhaps some expedient to consider?

```
add_action('init', 'add_sexes', 100);

function add_gender()
{
    wp_insert_term(
      'Male', // the term 
      'Gender', // the taxonomy
      array(
        'slug' => 'Male'
      )
    );
}
```

The goal is to insert 4 custom taxonomy by default when the plugin is activated. Actually nobody knows how to do that?

Comment: There is no code in your question to debug, so I don't know what the activator.php file does or what the custom taxonomy you're referring to is, or the processing step you mentioned. You need to include this code in your question or people won't understand what you're question is about. I went to the site you linked to and generated a plugin but found no custom taxonomies. Update your question using the edit link to explain and include code, remember a question should contain all the details needed to answer it, this isn't a discussion thread

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I just updated my ticket with the code. I hope it is clearer this way. Sorry for my English

Comment: hmm the code in your question will insert a term one very single page load, not just once. I would also advise against _sexes_, and use _gender_ instead which carries fewer connotations

Comment: Is there a similar code that allows me to add some taxonomy categories ONLY upon plugin activation? Obviously the user will be able to update or modify them, I just need them as a draft to make the user understand the usage